# Need a help in transposing the horizontal data to vertically arranged using powershell

Tags: powershell

Need a help in transposing the horizontal data to vertically arranged using PowerShell script

Input

```
12,15,45,56 & 54
```

Output

```
12
15
45
56
54
```

Comment: By the looks of it you're looking for either `.split(',')` or `-split ','` though your question is lacking and unclear.

Comment: If you need to deal with separators exactly as shown: `'12,15,45,56 & 54' -split ',| & '`